# What is (double (^)(int))foofoo

Tags: c++, casting, block, objective-c-blocks

There is [an example on cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28double+%28%5E%29%28int%29%29foofoo) that goes `(double (^)(int))foofoo` means ***cast foofoo into block (int) returning double***.

What does it mean to *cast foofoo into a "block" of int*?  What does the symbol `^` exactly mean in this context.  Usually it is bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a GCC extension made by Apple, and implemented also in Clang. Blocks are small unnamed functions and that syntax is the type of a block. See [Block Language Spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt).