# What is a block in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is (double (^)(int))foofoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551999/what-is-double-intfoofoo)

I've tried searching for a definition on Google and SO and I found examples in which they are used but not clearly defined. By "block" I mean the caret symbol (`^`). I found it [on a site where cdecl they described](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=cast%20foo%20into%20block%28int%2C%20long%20long%29%20returning%20double):

```
(double (^)(int, long long )) foo
```

as

> `cast foo into block(int, long long) returning double`

I've never once seen this symbol used before today. Can anyone clearly describe what a block is and include with it a minimal working example? Thanks.

Comment: This use of the `^` is not part of standard C++. But Objective C has blocks; haven't checked the syntax, but that could be it.

Comment: That's a managed pointer in C++/CLI. It's not in C++.

Comment: @chris C++/CLI uses the caret for that purpose, but is that really what is done here?

Comment: That's an [Objective C block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Error: requires C++/CLI enabled! VC++ 2010

Answer (score 8):

[Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29) are a non-standard extension to the C (and not only to the Objective-C) language by Apple. They realize [closures (lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), etc., however you call them) - basically they're unnamed function-like entities, enclosing code that can be called. They facilitate writing for example event-driven code, where callbacks are used exhaustively.