# Is there a feature in c++ that equivalent to the "block" in objective c?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

as the title said.
Is there a feature in c++ that equivalent to the "block" in objective c?
thanks.

Comment: In case you're wondering, your question was probably down-voted because this would have been really easy to answer with a quick google search.

Comment: @doctordoder I can't agree with that. In order to answer this (since I'm quite comfortable with C++), I've started reading about _blocks_. And I have to admit - I can't find what is a "_block_". The only things I can find is "_how to define a block_", which isn't quite helpful in this particular case. It actually took me some time to find out that "_a block is a self-contained, autonomous code fragment, existing always into the scope of another programming structure, as for example the body of a method_", which means its just a normal code fragment... I spent too much time on this question :|

Comment: @PawełStawarz Google "what is a block in objective c", and the first link is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html. Here is a quote from the first paragraph that you, being so comfortable with C++, should understand: "Blocks are Objective-C objects, which means they can be added to collections like NSArray or NSDictionary. They also have the ability to capture values from the enclosing scope, making them similar to closures or lambdas in other programming languages."

Comment: @doctordoder Well then - from the description you provided - I would say they're more like _functors_ ("...objects (...) have the ability to capture values from enclosing scope...") than _lambdas_.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Nope. Lambdas can also capture values from the enclosing scope.

Comment: @PawełStawarz That's what the capture list is for: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Comment: @doctordoder I know lambas _can_ capture values. Still lambas aren't objects AFAIK. So the description has more in common with _functors_, since they can also "_capture_" values.

Answer (score 1):

lambdas?

```
[&](){
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use std::function(lambda function) in c++ 11. These functions works like the blocks in objective c

> Definition

```
typedef std::function<void(std::string message, bool status)> LoginCallback
```

> Using in Class functions

```
void loginUser(std::string email, std::string password, LoginCallback loginCallback)
```

Assuming the above function is in the LoginClass

> Function Call

```
loginClassObj.loginUser("abc@xyz.com", "password", [this](std::string message, bool status){//Callback will received here});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a non-standard extension to the C. and it is closure to the [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) functions, basically they're unnamed function-like entities, enclosing code that can be called. They facilitate writing for example event-driven code, where callbacks are used exhaustively.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270079/what-is-a-block-in-c)